# Java WAS thread Hung

Tags: java, websphere

I'm facing an issue with java and was, i need to execute an sp which brings about 120k rows, 
the query in the database works fine, it takes only a few seconds to return the results,
the thing is, it's not working with the java, the rational IBM software says this:

```
ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "Webcontent : 4" (00000001) has been active for 700000 milliseconds
```

i read that i could use this to use multithread to execute the java

```
java.util.concurrent.Executor
```

is that true? will this solve this issue? 
if not, how could i solve this?

Btw i work on a virtual machine, with only one core.

Comment: If the query only "takes a few seconds" but in Java you've been waiting for 700000, there's something else going on that an `Executor` probably isn't going to fix

Comment: Without seeing your code it is hard to give you advice on this

Comment: To help analyze this problem, it is recommended to do a series of thread dumps using kill -3 in order to see what the thread is doing for the minutes it is running.  You would start the request that kicks off the work and then every 15 to 30 seconds do kill -3 operations to get thread dumps and look at what the offending thread is doing.

Comment: How big is your java heap, and how full? Are you running GC logging to provide visibility to heap health?
The behavior you describe could occur if the heap is too small to readily accommodate the 120K rows being ingested from the DB. As the heap fills up, the JVM will spend more time doing GC and less doing real work, causing user tasks like your thread to slow down.

Comment: A related question is how much memory your VM has, versus how much memory the 120K rows from the DB requires, when stored as a set of Java objects on the heap. If the JVM runs out of RAM and starts swapping to disk, it will run very very slowly.

Comment: Using an Executor won't help.  The sp call is a single-threaded op so an executor would be overkill.

Comment: @GaryDeVal the machine has 5.36gb, the java maxheapsize is 256mb, the initialheapsize is 88mb, i don't know how to check how many memory the query requires

Comment: @FRowe my virtual machine has only one core, does that affect the performance?? if the hardware is superior, is that reflected in a boost of performance?

Comment: To answer your question to Gary.  Looking at the verbose GC data will be important to determine your heap usage.  You can also use monitoring tools like jconsole to see your heap usage.  I would suggest trying to increase your heap size as an experiment to see the impact it has on your scenario.  I would start with 2 GB and go from there.